# Growth in old gen memory usage always means memory leak in Java?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

We have several VMs which are running data service in production, client sends Restful HTTP requests to data service, the load is kind of heavy (500 requests per second per host in general) and load is always balanced on each VM. We have same configuration on all hosts (2 CPUs, `-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`)

Two days ago, we saw old gen heap usage start growing on 5 of those VMs (300 MB per day), old gen heap usage on other ones stay the same (around 80 MB), we are trying to identify the root cause, may I ask if this is a memory leak issue or just a normal situation? Does growth in old gen memory usage always mean memory leak in Java?

Thanks.

Update: We just restarted those 5 hosts yesterday, old gen heap usage on all of them went back to normal as other ones, however, after the peak load we had this morning, the old gen heap usage on one of them started growing again...

Comment: I'm a newbie with these things, but I thought the GC was supposed to completely prevent memory leaks. In other words, I thought memory leak and java were never in the same sentence.

Comment: Java only GCs memory that is not referenced. If you create a for loop that keeps adding new objects to a list you will run out of memory before you can say blueberry pie.

Comment: @Takendarkk It's not impossible for java to have a memory leak, but there'd have to be a bug in the GC itself. I believe there have been cases like that, don't quote me on that though.

Comment: @NatanCox I'm not sure a memory leak is really the same as simply using up all your memory.

Comment: @Nata It's entirely possible to have a memory leak in Java -- for example, putting more and more data into a `HashMap` that you're using as a cache, without any eviction / expiration policy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Does growth in old gen memory usage always mean memory leak in java?*

Not necessarily.

The concurrent mark sweep garbage collector does not compact the old gen during collection.  So under sufficient memory load, it's possible to get a large amount of fragmentation, making it impossible to reclaim enough memory to allow promotion of tenured objects into the old gen space.

Try turning on these params and see what's going on:

> -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1

Look for promotion failures and frequent full GC sweeps that fail to free up a lot of memory.

If you're using Java 7 or higher you can try switching to the [G1 collector](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/index.html) (-XX:+UseG1GC instead of -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC).  This is a compacting collector which avoids some of the above issues.

If you're still running into problems after that, then I'd look to your code to see if something is hanging onto object references when it shouldn't.

Edit: since this is happening on some hosts and not others, I'd lean towards a code issue, perhaps related to unexpected user input, since it only occurs sporadically.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! We have already had the -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails settings, I checked there is no promotion failures for last 7 days. Yes, we are using Java 7 and we will try G1.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are describing is a memory leak. Because for me a memory leak is when your memory increases in time without any good reason or without developers understanding why. Which probably implies that some data you actually do not need is still kept in memory probably as a result of a bug.

I would consider using a good profiler to get to the root cause. It is probably easiest. I don't know if I'm allowed to name products here but JProfiler saved my team in multiple projects I worked on.

Comment: If the memory grows infinitely it would be, however if it can go down it might not be.